# Dynamic form combobox works only when clicked the right mouse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have a parent div name droppable and i have a image as a child wrapped in another div. On double click of that image i'm appending another image for it. On the click event of that image i'm appending a dynamic form which consist of a combo box with values. I have `event.stopPropagation();` accordingly to stop clicks bubbling. follwing is the code

```
//parent div click
    $("#droppable").click(function(event) {
     alert(111);

        });

//first child image double click

$("#clone"+count).dblclick(function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();

      var attrId=$(this).attr('id');

      var config=$('<span id=\"configconfigImg' + count + '\" class=\"config\" title=\"Configuration\"> <img id=\"configImg' + count + '\" class=\"configs configClone' + count + '\" src=\"images/configSymbol.png\"></span>');

      $("#"+attrId).append(config);

      //second child click function
      $('.configClone'+count).on('click', function (event) {

            event.stopPropagation();


            $(this).addClass("selected"+attrId).parent().append('<div id="pop' + attrId + '" class="messagepop pop' + attrId + '"><form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages"><p><label for="definedStream">Please select the stream</label><select id="definedStreams"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option></select></p></form></div>');

           //form div class click function used to stop propagating parent clicks when clicks on the form

           $(".pop"+attrId).click(function(event) {
                              alert(555);
                              event.stopPropagation();


           });

    });

 });
```

Now in the form when i click on the combo box it does not list down the results. but when i right click on it it works and from that moment on the left click works. I cannot find what the cause of it. Please help

Comment: can you show html code or fiddle.

Comment: i only have the parent div in html with draggable objects. image clones are dragged onto parent div. $("#clone"+count) is one of those clones.i added some more code to make it understanable